# displaying date in edit text android

Tags: android, datetime, android-edittext

In my application i have edit text that will show the current date and time initially . If i change the date to some other date and when i tried to use gettext() i am still getting the current date. can anyone help. This is my code to set initial value in edit text

```
TaskTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTaskTime);
        Date date = new Date();
        java.text.DateFormat dateFormat =    android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
        TaskDate.setText(dateFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: In your above code its been clearly written to get the current date so you are getting current date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get the current date because , `Date date = new Date();` this function always returns the current date .

So you need to use the `Calendar` object to get the current date and time .

### Example

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
String strDate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
```

Here in dateFormat you have to declare your date format . `dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"` like .

Answer (score 3):

Most of the use of date object is obsolete in Android, you should use Calendar : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html